# Server 2008 ime keeps changine few minutes delay

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am facing serious problem 
I have 2008 server and i am running web based applications.
I notice that the time of the server is keep changing .the minutes delay little .I set it many times and i notice next day it is delay few seconds and after days the minutes delayed.
I wish to solve this problem ASAP.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Set up time synchronization on your server.